# What file should I edit to change the wordpress blog post list

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

What files should I edit to change the structure and content of the posts echoed in the `index.php` page ?

The ones with circles around them..

[image]

I tried editing `content.php` because it had the `<article>` tag in the begining but it's not it.. it's the template of the post after you click on it. and not before.

I just want to edit the post previews "boxes", (To add the author picture.. change the elements positionings.. etc') When editing content.php it edits the post itself (for example, after I click on a post, I still see the post edits I made.

Which file is the right one?

**Using wordpress 4.1 Twentyfifteen theme

Comment: It might help if you post what version of Wordpress you are using and what template you are using (or if it's custom built).

Comment: Hi mate, I edited and added some more explanations

Comment: Note: Do not edit the theme directly. Your changes will be overwritten when the theme is updated. [Create a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and do your changes there.

Answer (score 0):

just edit these in your wp-admin area. Go to `Settings->Reading` and choose post page is your blog page.

After that just you had to change these in `index.php` file where is your php code added for calling blog page.

And if you want to change blog title and their description at that time you had to go in `content.php` file.

Happy :)

Comment: I already did all of this. 
I just want to edit the post previews "boxes", (To add the author picture.. change the elements positionings.. etc')
When editing content.php it edits the post itself (for example, after I click on a post, I still see the post edits I made.

Comment: @Hatul sorry ! i don't understand what are you saying .

Comment: When you write a posts, you get a "list" of them in the main blog page, which index.php is responsible echoing. right? 
so now i have 5 posts echoed in my blog page. 
I want to edit their structure. add them more tags for example. 
editing content.php makes changes in the post itself, which is not something I want. 
I want only to change the structure on the boxes displayed in blog page.

Comment: nono, it's echoing it fine. 
this is the part that is responsible echoing:

Comment: <?php
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

   endwhile;
 
   the_posts_pagination( array(
    'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
   ) );

  else :
   get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

  endif;
  ?>

Comment: and I want to change the structure of what it's echoing. 
I want to change the HTML of a single box post

Comment: So now goto content.php on that top there is one tag named as `<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>` changed on that it will displayed whole HTML file on blog page.

Comment: But I want to have different displays when entering a post-page. 
When I change the code on content.php it changes the code on the post-page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71153/discussion-between-kuldip-makadiya-and-hatul).

Comment: I want it to look like this: i.stack.imgur.com/BGHLO.png 
and in a different way on the Post-Page page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want edit this list page layout.

first check your post type and then go on content-***.php.
all content come on that post type Template.

Example:
Your post type is page,then go content-page.php file and change on that.

Comment: So should I edit the content.php and then edit a new content-***.php, and use content-***.php for the post-page and content.php for the output of the index.php page? 
That's what you ate saying?

Comment: no,you only edit on single file which is use for listout your post.you edit only content-page.php file.

Comment: Oh, SO.. 
content.php = for a single post in the index.php main page. and content-page.php = is displayed after clicking on the post in the index page?

Comment: yes,content.php use for the single ,search ,archive content. so you chage on content-page.php file.

Comment: Hmm.. I tested it now. 
I added some text in content.php and I got the text in the page of the post too. 
I added some text in content-page.php and nothing happened. 
:/

Comment: you fetch archive content so on that page so it take rom the content.php file.